# 2.1.5 Critical Error on startup

Tags: neo4j

I got Neo4j working on my Ubuntu Server, but after a update of Openssl and a reboot, i only get critical errors at startup.

I removed neo4j and reinstalled it (removed my manual Installation and installed it as a package with apt-get )

Still errors at startup and the Java stacktrace is not helpfull for me.

My Java looks fine and can run all other java Applications, i use:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Hope someone knows an answer to it.

**Here is the ErrorLog:**

```
4-10-20 12:27:28.908+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2014-10-20 12:29:36.997+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Exception when stopping org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@a0e0ab9 java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.stop(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:499)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.stop(XaDataSourceManager.java:185)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:123)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:343)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase$1.newGraphDatabase(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:45)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:167)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.writeInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:744)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:724)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.write(StoreFileChannel.java:51)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.writeAll(StoreFileChannel.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.writeOut(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:162)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.force(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:171)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.releaseCurrentLogFile(XaLogicalLog.java:614)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.close(XaLogicalLog.java:639)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:69)
    ... 14 more
2014-10-20 12:29:36.999+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Exception when stopping org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@4f325e80 Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@a0e0ab9' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@a0e0ab9' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:532)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.stop(XaDataSourceManager.java:185)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:123)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:343)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase$1.newGraphDatabase(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:45)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:167)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.stop(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:499)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.writeInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:744)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:724)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.write(StoreFileChannel.java:51)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.writeAll(StoreFileChannel.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.writeOut(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:162)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.force(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:171)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.releaseCurrentLogFile(XaLogicalLog.java:614)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.close(XaLogicalLog.java:639)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:69)
    ... 14 more
2014-10-20 12:29:37.000+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Lifecycle exception Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@4f325e80' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@4f325e80' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:532)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:123)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:343)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase$1.newGraphDatabase(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:45)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:167)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@a0e0ab9' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:532)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.stop(XaDataSourceManager.java:185)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.stop(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:499)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.writeInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:744)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:724)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.write(StoreFileChannel.java:51)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.writeAll(StoreFileChannel.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.writeOut(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:162)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.force(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:171)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.releaseCurrentLogFile(XaLogicalLog.java:614)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.close(XaLogicalLog.java:639)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:69)
    ... 14 more
2014-10-20 12:29:37.002+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Chained lifecycle exception Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@7d1fdb25' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@7d1fdb25' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:343)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase$1.newGraphDatabase(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:45)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:167)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension@76717dc9' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.start(KernelExtensions.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource@52f1a4a9' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.bringToState(LifeSupport.java:415)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.add(LifeSupport.java:326)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.registerDataSource(XaDataSourceManager.java:236)
    at org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension.start(LuceneKernelExtension.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.<init>(IndexProviderStore.java:85)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.newIndexStore(LuceneDataSource.java:320)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.start(LuceneDataSource.java:230)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(FileChannelImpl.java:290)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.position(StoreFileChannel.java:105)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.position(StoreFileChannel.java:28)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.write(IndexProviderStore.java:169)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.create(IndexProviderStore.java:153)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.<init>(IndexProviderStore.java:61)
    ... 19 more
2014-10-20 12:29:37.006+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
```

Comment: Would you be able to share your messages.log ? And perhaps your store-files with us? Can you send me an email to michael at neo4j.org

Comment: I have sent you a mail containing the console/message.log with a fresh Database.